# Installing QGIS processing tools in independent Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, installation

I want to use the inbuilt functionality of the processing tools of QGIS in an independent (means separate Python script). But I'm unable to install the relative package outside of QGIS.

How can I install processing tools of QGIS using `pip`?

Comment: I am 99.99% sure this is not possible as the Processing tools are tightly dependent on the QGIS core and you cannot use them if you do not have the whole QGIS package installed.

Comment: Is it possible to install QGIS (as a package) using pip?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: This is is a possible work around. 
 https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You can install QGIS by Conda Environment with conda-forge channel with command:

`conda install qgis --channel conda-forge`

After install in a conda environment, it's possible create a standalone PyQGIS with this env.